# Why can't I see any requests to DLLs

Tags: blazor

I created a project in VS2019 and selected Blazor "Web Asssembly App" which is for Blazor client apps.

Running the app from VS, Chrome opens and the Blazor app works fine.

But in the Network tab in Chrome, I cannot see any requests to any DLLs (even running in Release)

I don't understand how the Blazor client app works, shouldn't I see the browser requests to get the DLL files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> shouldn't I see the browser requests to get the DLL files?

Yes, but they are agressively cached. They are loaded on the first run only, and that ususally is before you have the Network tab open.

With your app loaded and running, in Dev Tools, go to the Application tab an select Cache. Clear it.

Then switch back to the Network tab and reload.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought Ctrl+F5 does that already, I thought it's not using the cache at all

Comment: Blazor uses the JS Cache API, not the 'normal' HTTP caching.